# Regardning IAP and allowing payments outside the App Store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Apple says the following in thier guidelines / rules:

11.14 **“Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video and cloud storage) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the App, as long as there is no button or external link in the App to purchase the approved content. Apple will only receive a portion of revenues for content purchased inside the App”**

As of today we are one of Sweden's bestselling apps using IAP. Since the new tax rules in EU we realy would like to skip both Apple and Google. We only offer our content thru our apps (100% app company).

Can you offer subscriptions outside an app if all you do is informing the userbase about cheaper subscriptions on a webbpage with a 10% disscount **without having a link or button to it**. Just plain text informing about it?

If you read the 11.14 rule it feels like this scenario would be allowed? But at the same time there is some kind of grey-area in this situation, how far can you go and what is allowed and what not? This is not a programming questions and I understand it. But I would appreciate the knowledge and experience people do have on this matter.

Reagards